# TypeError: element is null [Break On This Error] element.style.display = 'none'; in magento

Tags: magento

I am facing the problem to load the magento onepage checkout. When I click on the proceed to checkout button then the onepage checkout not loaded the completely only it loads only the 2 steps and when I checked it through the firebug it displays the error

> TypeError: element is null [Break On This Error] element.style.display = 'none'; In magento

Comment: This is a javascript error, I think you know this. Is this error thrown if you use the default/default templates? I hope you didn't change them. If no, your template misses something. So I guess you deleted some html id or class which is needed.

Comment: Yes, I got this same error. I debugged it by closing div, I found that error was gone when I closed header div and after deep digging, it was form.mini.phtml in catelogsearch folder, the JavaScript in this page using a div which was deleted by me so that made element null.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. In my case, it was because in checkout.js on events it was showing and hiding some elements which i had removed. So application was searching for them and was returning null since it couldnt find it. Check for steps which you have deleted or commented.